Is there a unique way to define 'satisfying' of a satisfying extension on the expected value of bounded sets, which solves two problems?
Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Suppose $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is Borel and $\mathcal{U}$ is the set of all unbounded $A$. Also, $\text{dim}_{\text{H}}(\cdot)$ is the Hausdorff dimension while $\mathcal{H}^{\text{dim}_{\text{H}}(\cdot)}(\cdot)$ is the Hausdorff measure in its dimension on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.
Notice that the expected value of $A$, w.r.t the Hausdorff measure in its dimension, is:
$$\text{Avg}(A)=\frac{1}{\mathcal{H}^{\text{dim}_{\text{H}}(A)}(A)}\int_{A}(x_1,\cdot\cdot\cdot,x_n) \, d\mathcal{H}^{\text{dim}_{\text{H}}(A)}$$
Nevertheless, we have the following problems:

Problem 1: When $A$ is this set, $\text{Avg}(A)$ is undefined.


Problem 2: When $\,\mathcal{U}^{\prime}\subseteq\mathcal{U}$ is the set of all $A$ with a finite $\text{Avg}(A)$, where the cardinality is $|\cdot|$, then $|\mathcal{U}^{\prime}|<|\mathcal{U}|$ (i.e., $\mathcal{U}^{\prime}$ is "measure zero" in  $\mathcal{U}$).

We fix both problems using the approach, where we discuss the term 'satisfying' after:

Approach: We want an unique, satisfying extension of the expected value of $A$, w.r.t the Hausdorff measure in its dimension, on bounded sets to $A$, which take finite values only, such that when $\,\mathcal{U}^{\prime\prime}\subseteq\mathcal{U}$ is the set of all $A$ with this extension:

$|\,\mathcal{U}\setminus\mathcal{U}^{\prime\prime}|<|\,\mathcal{U}^{\prime\prime}|$ (i.e., $\mathcal{U}^{\prime\prime}$ is "almost everywhere" in $\mathcal{U}$)
If 1. isn't true, then $|\,\mathcal{U}^{\prime\prime}|=|\,\mathcal{U}\setminus\mathcal{U}^{\prime\prime}|$


Question: Is there a unique way to define 'satisfying' to solve problems 1 and 2? For a possible answer, see this and this article.
Edit: I combined both papers into this article.
Edit: I posted a third version with examples, motivations, and explanations throughout.
